# Set ListView Scrollable

Tags: android

When I do a ListActivity my ListView works correctly : I can scroll by dragging with the TouchScreen or with the Mouse Wheel.
However when I incorporate a ListView in a layout (with buttons, textview, linearLayouts, ect... ) I can't scroll it by dragging, I can just scroll with the mouse wheel.

How can I enable the "touch" scroll of a listView (outside a list activity) ?

Comment: Can you show your layout?  What are the contents of the ListView items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've found out ! Sorry it's entirely my fault : my layout is really complex and I've shown you the part containing the listView but I had forgotten that my whole screen was embedded in a scrollview. And so there was a conflict between this listView and the ScrollView parent.

Excuse me again and thank you for your answers and advises !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:isScrollContainer="true"` to your ListView definition.  That ought to do it.

Another couple points of advice:

- You can have the ListView automatically show the "Not found" TextView by using `ListView.setEmptyView()`
- You should use `dip` or `pt` for your fonts, not `sp`.  Try your app out on 3 different AVDs, one with a QVGA skin, one with HVGA, and one with WVGA, and I think you'll see what I mean.  I would recommend `pt` except for the fact that the Droid has a glaring bug which causes font points to be incorrectly scaled.  Try dips instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advices :) , android:isScrollContainer="true" doesn't work :( .
I really don't know why it's not working, as I told you my ListActivity scroll perfectly (touch event + trackball) but this ListView just scroll with the trackball. I can click/touch an item but can't scroll by dragging.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/results_panel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/panel_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
android:visibility="invisible">         
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/results"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:shadowColor="#7299e1"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/results_panel_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/not_found"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>      
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/results_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>           
</LinearLayout>
```

The first linear layout Visibility is set programmaticaly to visible (so don't worry about that;)).

The first TextView is a title which appear above the ListView.

The second TextView Visibility is set to visible if I have no item otherwise to gone.

The ListView display the items and is set to visible if I have items otherwise to gone.

The items are Strings in a string Array displayed with an Array adapter.